# Functions in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

How to concatenate 2 tuples into a variable in SQL.

My tuples look something like this after a normal query:

```
name                        |       code    
DatabaseManagementSystem    |    COMP1234
```

My code right now looks something like this:

```
create or replace function concat(text) returns text
as $$`
    select name, code
    from subjects
    where code = 'text'
    $$ language sql;
```

What I need it to do is take the code as input and assign the variable text to "code name" and return text

Expected input (text) - COMP1234

Expected Output (text) - DatabaseManagementSystem COMP1234

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc?